# Is data tile of ADAS_ATTRIB_FCX of Platform Data Extension API available in India

Tags: here-api

I'm 90-day Free Trial User.

I use Platform Data Extension API.
I called tile URI. When tile of USA was requested, returned a data.
But, when tile of India, returned empty data.

For example.

(Actually YOUR_APP_ID and YOUR_APP_CODE are generated value at project web page of my account)

1. OK, for Frankfurt in Germany.

> https://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/tile.json?layer=ADAS_ATTRIB_FC3&level=11&tilex=2146&tiley=1594&app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}

2. OK, for Palo Alto in USA

I changed parameter to below. 
(Stackoverflow require 10 reputation for writing more than two URL)

> tile.json?layer=ADAS_ATTRIB_FC3&level=11&tilex=658&tiley=1449&app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}

3. NG, for New Delhi in India

> tile.json?layer=ADAS_ATTRIB_FC3&level=11&tilex=2926&tiley=1349&app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}

In this case, just returned below data.

> {"Rows":[]}

Answer (score 0):

I queried by email. I got answer that ADAS data is not available in India.